# Abrir um arquivo em executável usando VB ou CMD

Tags: visual-basic-6, batch, cmd

Como abrir um arquivo de qualquer extensão, como por exemplo - `Paçoca.legalcara` numa executável como - `algo.exe` utilizando **CMD** ou **VB**?

Obs.: O caminho deve ser relativo, o que significa que todos estão na mesma pasta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Para uso na mesma pasta e usando caminhos relativos para chamada do executável (**algo.exe**) passando o argumento/arquivo(**Paçoca.legalcara**)

---

> **Em VB**

---

```VBS
Dim oFSO 
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sScriptDir = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
set shell=CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shell.ShellExecute "algo.exe",sScriptDir+"\Paçoca.legalcara z -S -v ",sScriptDir, , 1
set shell=nothing
```

**Obs.:** Para fins de testes, foram assim renomeados:

arquivo **`madplay.exe`**  para **`algo.exe`**

aqruivo **`Redemption Song.mp3`** para **`Paçoca.legalcara`**

---

> **Em CMD**

---

```VBS
pushd "caminho_de_sua_pasta" && .\algo.exe ".\Paçoca.legalcara" & popd

rem :: ou ..

pushd "caminho_de_sua_pasta" && start "" .\algo.exe ".\Paçoca.legalcara" & popd

rem :: ou ..

cd /d  "caminho_de_sua_pasta" && .\algo.exe ".\Paçoca.legalcara"

rem :: ou ..

cd /d "caminho_de_sua_pasta" && start "" .\algo.exe ".\Paçoca.legalcara"
```

Answer (score 3):

No VB você pode usar os argumentos, por exemplo chamar o notepad:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", "c:\arquivo.txt")
```

E no cmd seria algo como:

```
start "notepad.exe" "c:\arquivo.txt"
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda =)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento  Bom tarde tchê! essa parte: **`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", "c:\arquivo.txt")`** é **`C#`** não **`VBs`**

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe na verdade é VB.net, mas sim a tag é sobre vb6, logo não seria isto o correto. Estarei editando em breve, obrigado